# AVD cannot connect to internet

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I accidently remove some softwares maybe vmware or something. Now all my AVD cannot connect to internet. It work good before, so I think because I uninstall something relative to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use SDK manager to Remove and Install Android Emulator again and it solve my problem.